# Add new .xlsx to an existing .xlsx in sheet(tab)

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I have one code that goes like below..

#After performing some operation using pandas I have written df to the .xlsx

```
df.to_excel('file5.xlsx',index=False) # This excel has a single tab(sheet) inside
```

Then I have another .xlsx file (already provided) `Final.xlsx` , that has multiple tab(sheet) inside it like `file1,file2,file3,file4` . I want to add the newly create `file5.xls` to the `Final.xlsx` as new sheet after sheet `file4` .

Below answer provided by Anky, it is adding sheet the `xlsx file5.xlsx` to 'Final.xlsx' but the content inside sheets `file1 2 3 4` is getting missed, format broken and also data is missing ...

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('foo.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df1=pd.read_excel('file5.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer, "new",index=False)

writer.save()
```

Need help to fix this..

I have asked this in separate question - [Data missing, format changed in .xlsx file having multiple sheets using pandas, openpyxl while adding new sheet in existing .xlsx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074771/data-missing-format-changed-in-xlsx-file-having-multiple-sheets-using-pandas)

Comment: what is "an excel"? Excel is the name of a spreadsheet software. With this software you can create **workbooks** that have one or more **worksheets** to organize data and perform calculations. There is no such thing as "an excel". Please use accurate terms, not brand names, for things you need help with.

Comment: @teylyn  I mean `.xlsx ` file , updated /

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('foo.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, "file5",index=False)

writer.save()
```

Sheetname can be whatever you want to keep ex: file5

Comment: you have to read your xlsx file as a df using read_excel and then write out using the code above or you can directly write the df which you have instead of saving it to file5

Comment: foo.xlsx is the excel file which has multiple sheets, you want to write your df into foo.xlsx , so dont save it as an excel file file5, instead use the code and name the sheetname as file5

Comment: Just a question , how this code will detect `file5.xlsx` here , if not provided  that was already created ..

Comment: so, you dont need to create the file5.xlsx ,  you are putting the df into file5.xlsx, instead you create a sheet named file5 write the df directly into foo.xlsx. If making the file5.xlsx is absolutely mandatory, you can write the df into file5.xlsx and read it back again using read_excel, then use that dfnew = pd.read_excel('file5.xlsx') in my code, replace dfnew with df in that case.

Comment: Its working, `file5` is getting added in sheet, however `file1 to file4` content inside it is getting colored with different color, strange ?

Comment: Yeah, shouldnot be the case, may be some formatting issues with excel. You can close all excel and open and check :) . however if you are satisfied with the answer, pl accept. :) Happy coding

Comment: Even Lot of content gets missing from `file to file5`, Any way it can be fixed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179007/discussion-between-anky-91-and-stevej).